# Cloud Firestore node.js invalid use of type "object" as a Firestore argument

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My question is about why I can't seem to pass data into a Firestore database. I'm running code on node.js trying to parse data coming from my Firebase Firestore database and then return information back to the database. Retrieval of the information works fine, but an error message that I cannot escape for the life of me keeps appearing when trying to pass data back to the database.

```
if(message.type = "0") {
  console.log(0)
  db.collection("outbox").doc("messageID").set({message: "test message"})
}
```

On trying to process the last line of code, the following error message appears:

> Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Invalid use of type "object" as a Firestore argument.

My database is structured as **outbox/messageID/message**. Message holds a string value and I'm using the admin SDK so write issues aren't a problem. I'm doing something wrong with passing the object along to Firebase but I just can't figure it out. This is my first time working with Cloud Firestore and node.js but I've done small-scale projects in HTML/JS before.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't use an argument `data` anywhere. Are you sure this is the exact code that raises that error? If so, can you edit your question to include the complete stack trace?

Comment: When commenting out the 3rd line of code the error goes away. I can't get a stack trace because I am running the code on repl.it and as far as I know you can't do that. Sorry for being unhelpful...

Comment: In that case, can you share a repl.it (or jsbin, or stackblitz, or similar) link that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an internal error with the way firestore checks if a value is an array.

I have the same issue trying a simple

```
db.collection('Test').add({ foo: 'bar' })
```

Which leads to

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Invalid use of type "object" as a Firestore argument
```

After digging into firebase source code i found they check if an object is an object, based on this test :

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(input) === Object.prototype
```

Which is false in some environments for some unknwon reasons (In my case: Node v10.15.3 CLI)

As a workaround if you temporary needs to have this works, you may edit your node module source code in this file : `node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js`

Change the isPlainObject function to :

```
function isPlainObject(input) {
    return util_1.isObject(input);
}
```

Comment: Note: I tried to enforce the prototype of { foo: 'bar' } to Object.prototype, ... but it's not having any effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question; I'm glad to know that it wasn't an issue with my code. I was going insane trying to figure out what was wrong haha.

Comment: I was kind of crazy about it too ! :P II would like to know why the prototype is changed ... In my case, I think it may be node.js adding some stuff on objects when using the CLI ... but not sure at all :D

Comment: Thanks for finding the workaround @Poyoman, this was incredibly frustrating